# Partition of interval is countable

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider the arbitrary partition of the real non-empty interval $[a,b)$, into the disjoint sets $[\alpha(i),\beta(i))$ where $i\in I$ and $I$ is some index set. Why is it necessary that $I$ be countable? Isn't it true that $[a,b)$ contains an uncountable set that could serve as a source of candidates for the endpoints of the partition intervals?

Comment: There is a surjection from some subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ to the set of intervals.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Each interval contains a rational.

**Added:** The following is probably more explicit tha necessary. Let $r_1,r_2, r_3,\dots$ be an enumeration of the rationals. For each $i\in I$, let $n_i$ be the least index such that $r_{n_i}$ is in $[\alpha(i),\beta(i))$. Then the set $\{n_i\}$, as $i$ ranges over $I$, is a subset $M$  of the natural numbers, and the mapping $i\to n_i$ gives a bijection between $I$ and $M$. Thus $I$ must be finite or countably infinite.

Comment: I know that I have to construct a one-to-one mapping from $I$ to the rationals, but I don't see how to use the hint.

Comment: If you had an uncountable indexing set $I$, each set in $I$ would contain a rational. Hence there would be uncountably many rational numbers in the interval $[a,b)$, but the set of rationals is....